# package emmeans: if including less variables in an emmip model, what are the other variables set to in the emmeans model?

Tags: r, emmeans

Say I have a linear model:

`fullmodel <-glm(outcome ~ map * pressor + group + x + y + z, data=data, family="binomial")`

And then want to construct a plot of a interaction terms analysis:

`graphedmodel <- emmip(fullmodel, pressor~map | group, at=list(map=seq(60,105,by=5), type = "r", CIs=TRUE)`

In graphedmodel, what are the values of all the other variables for x, y, z? Are they assumed to take their mean values? Are they simply excluded from the analysis?

Not troubleshooting; the model works. I want to know how the model behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is plotting estimated marginal means, and that means that any excluded factors are averaged-over, and any excluded numeric covariates are set to their means -- unless directed otherwise by optional specifications such as `at` or `cov.reduce`. In the question, I'd guess `x`, `y`, and `z` are numeric, so are set at their means.

Comment: I ran some tests empirically using the at= argument and as far as I can tell this is indeed the case. Continuous variables are set at their means from the original dataset (and the coefficients from the original regression model). Categorical variables, as far as I can tell, have the weighted average of the effects from the 2+ categories added to the regression model output.

Comment: There is a ton of documentation in the **emmeans** package. There is no need to speculate on what it does and test to see if it's true, because it's documented. Specifically to this question, see the help pages for `ref_grid()` first, then `emmeans()`.